# How to get case statement to differentiate based on hours of day

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting

UPDATED:

I am trying to do some color changes with my keyboard using [apexctl](https://github.com/tuxmark5/ApexCtl) depending on what time it is. But my case statement is giving me trouble.
I want to compare the time when the script runs, $zed to various possibilities that it could be, and set the lights accordingly.

But it gives me th default case every time. This outputs "Dude what?"

Why arent any of my cases working?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Use my keyboard as a clock
#https://github.com/tuxmark5/ApexCtl/issues
#set -vx
zed=`date +"%H"`  
echo $zed

off="000000"
white="FFFFFF"
orange="FF8000"
yellow="FFFF00"
lime="80FF00"
green="00FF00"
teal="00FF80"
turquoise="00FFFF"
sky="0080FF"
blue="0000FF"
purple="7F00FF"
fuschia="FF00FF"
lavender="FF007F"
red="FF0000"


  case $zed in
  0[0-3])
  #purple bluw logo
  apexctl colors -n 551A8B:8 -s 551A8B:8 -e 551A8B:8  -w 551A8B:8 -l 0000FF:8
  ;;
  0[4-9])
  #too early for this
  sudo apexctl colors -n $off:8 -s $off:8 -e $off:8  -w $off:8 -l $off:8
  ;;
  [10-12])
  #still too early for this
  apexctl colors -n $off:8 -s $off:8 -e $off:8  -w $off:8 -l $red:8
  ;;
  [13])
  apexctl colors -n $white:8 -s $white:8 -e $white:8  -w $white:8 -l $white:8
  ;;
  [14])
  apexctl colors -n $orange:8 -s $orange:8 -e $orange:8  -w $orange:8 -l $orange:8
  ;;
  [15])
  apexctl colors -n $yellow:8 -s $yellow:8 -e $yellow:8  -w $yellow:8 -l $yellow:8
  ;;
  [16])
  apexctl colors -n $lime:8 -s $lime:8 -e $lime:8  -w $lime:8 -l $lime:8
  ;;
  [17])
  apexctl colors -n $green:8 -s $green:8 -e $green:8  -w $green:8 -l $green:8
  ;; 
  [18])
  apexctl colors -n $teal:8 -s $teal:8 -e $teal:8  -w $teal:8 -l $teal:8
  ;;
  [19])
  apexctl colors -n $purple:8 -s $purple:8 -e $purple:8  -w $purple:8 -l $purple:8
  ;; 
  [20])
  apexctl colors -n $fuschia:8 -s $fuschia:8 -e $fuschia:8  -w $fuschia:8 -l $fuschia:8
  ;;
  [21-23])  
  apexctl colors -n $red:8 -s $red:8 -e $red:8  -w $red:8 -l $blue:8
  ;;
   *) 
   echo "Dude What?"
  ;;
 esac
```

Comment: Define "chokes"

Comment: Note in Hauke Laging's answer that there's a space after the `[`. That's **essential** because the `[` isn't mere grouping syntax, it's actually a command: it's a synonym of `test`. Also, you should (generally) quote parameter expansions; this is especially important inside `test` expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see what is happening with your `case` statements.  From the **Pattern Matching** section of the `bash` man page:

```
[...]  Matches any one of the enclosed characters.
```

For all of the hours from 10-23, the pattern matching is looking for any ***one*** of the enclosed characters.

**Option 1:**

```
1[0-2])
apexctl ...
;;

1[3])
apexctl ...
;;
```

**Option 2:**

```
10|11|12)
apexctl ...
;;

13)
apexctl ...
;;
```

**Note unrelated to the case functionality:**

Your 0-4 hour `apexctl` command is prepended with `sudo`.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: I meant to remove them. the script is intended to be run as root, via a cron job.

Answer (score 3):

You completely misunderstand the way `case` and `[ ]` work. What you need is `if ... elif ...`:

```
if [ "$zed" -eq 0 ] && [ "$zed" -le 3 ]; then
    : ...
elif [ "$zed" -gt 3 ] && [ "$zed" -lt 12 ]; then
    : ...
elif [ "$zed" -eq 27 ]; then
    : ...
else
    : ...
fi
```

`[ "$zed" -eq 0] && [ "$zed" -le 3 ]` doesn't make sense anyway because 0 is smaller than 3 i.e. it is the same like `[ "$zed" -le 3 ]` alone.